# Were the castes of the Selenites in "The First Men in the Moon" social or biological?

Tags: first-men-in-the-moon

The Selenites from *The First Men in the Moon* are divided into multiple distinct castes, but I have found conflicting information in whether these are biological castes, like the polymorphism seen in ants or bees, if they are more like social castes, where social stratification led to diverging forms, or if these castes are something else entirely.

[This wiki](https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/Selenite), which is the only source specific to the Selenites that I can find, claims that the castes are biological, yet most other sources imply social castes, and I am not sure if biological castes were known of when the story was written.

What were the Selenite castes supposed to be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   You say you've found conflicting information; what information have you found?  A summary of the research you've done can be of assistance to potential answerers.

Comment: @DavidW Does my edit help?

Comment: Are you more particularly interested in the 1900 H. G. Wells novel *The First Men in the Moon*, or the 1964 Harryhausen film "First Men in the Moon", or are you happy with information from either?

Comment: @Buzz I'd mainly like to know about the novel

Comment: Actually there are other film adapations of The first Men in the Moon.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men_in_the_Moon#Film_adaptations

Answer (score 4):

The full text is available [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1013/1013-h/1013-h.htm)—see chapter XXIV, "The Natural History of the Selenites", which makes clear that Selenites with different roles are biologically different, like ant colonies with queens vs. drones vs. worker ants.

> He does not mention the ant, but throughout his allusions the ant is continually being brought before my mind, in its sleepless activity, in its intelligence and social organisation, in its structure, and more particularly in the fact that it displays, in addition to the two forms, the male and the female form, that almost all other animals possess, a number of other sexless creatures, workers, soldiers, and the like, differing from one another in structure, character, power, and use, and yet all members of the same species. For these Selenites, also, have a great variety of forms. Of course, they are not only colossally greater in size than ants, but also, in Cavor’s opinion at least, in intelligence, morality, and social wisdom are they colossally greater than men. And instead of the four or five different forms of ant that are found, there are almost innumerably different forms of Selenite. I had endeavoured to indicate the very considerable difference observable in such Selenites of the outer crust as I happened to encounter; the differences in size and proportions were certainly as wide as the differences between the most widely separated races of men. But such differences as I saw fade absolutely to nothing in comparison with the huge distinctions of which Cavor tells. It would seem the exterior Selenites I saw were, indeed, mostly engaged in kindred occupations—mooncalf herds, butchers, fleshers, and the like. But within the moon, practically unsuspected by me, there are, it seems, a number of other sorts of Selenite, differing in size, differing in the relative size of part to part, differing in power and appearance, and yet not different species of creatures, but only different forms of one species, and retaining through all their variations a certain common likeness that marks their specific unity. The moon is, indeed, a sort of vast ant-hill, only, instead of there being only four or five sorts of ant, there are many hundred different sorts of Selenite, and almost every gradation between one sort and another.
>
> ...
>
> “Indeed, there seemed not two alike in all that jostling multitude. They differed in shape, they differed in size, they rang all the horrible changes on the theme of Selenite form! Some bulged and overhung, some ran about among the feet of their fellows. All of them had a grotesque and disquieting suggestion of an insect that has somehow contrived to mock humanity; but all seemed to present an incredible exaggeration of some particular feature: one had a vast right fore-limb, an enormous antennal arm, as it were; one seemed all leg, poised, as it were, on stilts; another protruded the edge of his face mask into a nose-like organ that made him startlingly human until one saw his expressionless gaping mouth. The strange and (except for the want of mandibles and palps) most insect-like head of the mooncalf-minders underwent, indeed, the most incredible transformations: here it was broad and low, here high and narrow; here its leathery brow was drawn out into horns and strange features; here it was whiskered and divided, and there with a grotesquely human profile. One distortion was particularly conspicuous. There were several brain cases distended like bladders to a huge size, with the face mask reduced to quite small proportions. There were several amazing forms, with heads reduced to microscopic proportions and blobby bodies; and fantastic, flimsy things that existed, it would seem, only as a basis for vast, trumpet-like protrusions of the lower part of the mask. And oddest of all, as it seemed to me for the moment, two or three of these weird inhabitants of a subterranean world, a world sheltered by innumerable miles of rock from sun or rain, carried umbrellas in their tentaculate hands—real terrestrial looking umbrellas! And then I thought of the parachutist I had watched descend.